# MySQL - How to optimize table for speed

Tags: mysql

First of all, I am still very new to PHP / mySQL so excuse my question if it is too simple for you :)

Here is my issue: I am currently working on storing a lot of data into a mysql database. It's basically a directory like archive for my son's school.

The structure is basically:

id, keyword, title, description, url, rank, hash

```
id is int 11
keyword is varchar 255
title is varchar 255
description is text
url is varchar 255
rank is int 2
hash is varchar 50
```

We plan to insert about 10 million rows containing the fields above and my mission is being able to query the database as fast as possible.

My query is always for an exact keyword.

For example:

```
select * from table where keyword = "keyword" limit 10
```

I really just need to query the keyword and not the title or description or anything else. There are a maximum of 10 results for each keyword - never more.

I have no real clue about mysql indexes and stuff but I read that it can improve speed if you have some indexes.

Now here is where I need help from a Pro. My mission is being able to run the fastest possible query, so it doesn't take too long to query the database. Since I am only looking up the keyword field, I am sure there is a way to make sure that even if you have millions of rows, that the results can be returned quickly.

What would you suggest that I should do. Should I set the keyword field to INDEX or do I have to watch anything else? Since I have no real clue about INDEXES, your help is appreciated, meaning I don't know if I should use indexes at all, or if I have to use them for everything like keyword, title, description and so on...

The database is updated frequently - in case it matters.

Do you think it's even possible to store millions of rows and doing a query in less than a second?

Any other suggestions such as custom my.cnf settings etc would be also helpful.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct - if you are only filtering on `keyword` in your `WHERE` clause, it should be indexed and you likely *will* see some execution speed improvement if you do.

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_keyword` ON `yourtable` (`keyword`)
```

You may be using a client like PHPMyAdmin which makes index creation easier than execution commands, but review [the MySQL documentation on `CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). Yours is a very run-of-the-mill case, so you won't need any special options.

Although this isn't the case for you (as you said there would be up to 10 rows per `keyword`), if you already had a unique constraint or `PRIMARY KEY` or `FOREIGN KEY` defined on `keyword`, it would function as an index as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add an index on the `keyword` column. It will increase the speed significantly. Then it should be no problem to query the data in milliseconds.

In generel you should put an index on fields you are using in your `where` clause. That way the DB can limit the data really fast and return the results.